# Can I report my WES GPA?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, gpa

Let's say my undergraduate institute has "GPA: 3.78" on its official transcript.
Then I requested [World Education Services (WES)](https://www.wes.org/) to evaluate my GPA based on their "standard" procedure, which results in a GPA of 3.83.

When applying to Ph.D. programs,

- Can/should I report a GPA of 3.83 instead of 3.78?
- Can/should I upload the PDF transcript from WES instead of/in addition to the one from my undergraduate institute?

Comment: Well, I think most institutions do not require you to have your transcripts evaluated by evaluators like WES, so it would be a mistake to only report the transcript provided by WES if the institutions you are going to apply require the OFFICIAL transcript. The WES transcript is by no means your official transcript.